# crear un spinner obteniendo array desde strings.xml

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Estoy creando mi primer proyecto en el cual quiero crear un spinner sin xml , que muestre un arrray que tengo declarada en string.xml.

```
<string-array name="tipodedatos">
    <item>INC</item>
    <item>BOL</item>
    <item>REC</item>
    <item>BTP</item>
</string-array>
```

Este extracto es parte del activity principal que tengo en la parte de java.

```
Spinner spdato=new Spinner(this);
```

ya de aquí no puedo seguir, he intentado buscar información pero no encuentro nada mas , espero que podáis ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero obtén el array de elementos:

```
String[] datos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tipodedatos);
```

Agrégalo a tu `Adapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.text, datos );
```

y configura el `Adapter` a tu `Spinner`:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: muchas gracias. ya no me da errores y funciona